# What difference between pclose and fclose in php

Tags: php, resources, pipe

I have some code that works with pipes and files.
At the end of operation my function should close resource.

Can I close a pipe resource with fclose?
It seems not hard for php to track how to close a resource but
I see 2 functions.

I create pipe with popen function.

Otherwise I need a method to distinguish pipe and file resources.

```
get_resource_type returns "stream" for both resources.
```

Or I have to implement expensive wrapper classes.

```
class PipeStream {
    public function __desctruct() { pclose($this->resource); }
}
class FileStream {
    public function __desctruct() { fclose($this->resource); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [`pclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php) . It is used to close a process resource created by [`popen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) rather then a named pipe.

If you are working with so called, named pipes, which are objects stored in the file system, use:

- posix_mkfifo() to create them
- fopen() to open them
- fclose() to close them

As you see, to create a fifo it requires the `posix` extension meaning that it will not work on Windows as Windows itself does not support named pipes (or the posix standard in general)

Comment: I have a problem with code reuse. And to have universal function now I see only 1 solution is to write wrapper classes like I did above. But it looks like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can open, close and read/write pipes like a regular file, no wrapper is required for this functionality. If you want to create them, it is. But don't forget when working with named pipes: This will not work on Windows.